# Сокращения в названиях предприятий и организаций

Tags: сокращения

Есть ли официальный перечень сокращений, используемых в названиях предприятий и организаций, которые можно без предварительной расшифровки использовать, например, в темах курсовых и дипломных проектов? Такие как ЗАО, ОАО, ООО, ГУП, ГУЗ, СОШ, ДШО и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальные словари сокращений.
Наиболее известным собранием аббревиатур является «Словарь сокращений русского языка» (сост. Д. И. Алексеев, И. Г. Гозман, Г. В. Сахаров). В первом издании 1963 г. (под ред. Б. Ф. Корицкого)насчитывалось 12 500 сокращений, в третьем (1983 г.) и четвертом (1984 г. – оба под редакцией Д. И. Алексеева) число сокращений значительно пополнилось и составило 17 700. В словаре расшифровываются сокращенные наименования государств, партий, организаций, учреждений, учебных заведений, производственных предприятий, марки машин, приборов, обозначения единиц измерений. В словаре даны сведения о типах аббревиатур, о произношении, ударении в сокращенных словах и их написании. Самым полным из когда-либо издававшихся словарей сокращений русского языка на сегодняшний день считается словарь под редакцией Е. Г. Коваленко (М., 1995). В нем дается расшифровка около 32 000 аббревиатур и других сокращений. В словаре представлены сокращения разного типа: инициальные сокращения (аббревиатуры), графические сокращения и сложносокращенные слова. Словарь имеет практическую направленность, поэтому система помет и пояснений в нем сведена к минимуму: сокращения приводятся без ударения, без грамматических помет и без указания произношения. Самый последний словарь сокращений под ред. И. В. Фаградянца (М., 2000) представляет собой дополнение к «Новому словарю сокращений русского языка» под ред. Е. Г. Коваленко (см. выше). Издание содержит около 10 000 новых сокращений. - 
Грамота.ру.

Comment: Словарей-то много, даже в сети есть, но ТС **официальный список** просил.

Answer (score 0):

Про "официальный" список я ничего не слушал, но по факту используют обычно те аббревиатуру, которые входят в фофициальные названия учреждений.  В противном случае обычно предваоительно расшифровывают, особенно в официальных документах.
~~~~~

Вот мне тут подсказали интересную мысль. В названиях органищзаций можно использовать любые сочетания букв и цифр. Ограничений нет. Т.е. включение в название любой аббревиатуры не противоречит никаким правилам. Проблемы (вполне, впрочем, преодолимые) возникают только при похожести названия на уже имеющееся или неблашозвучии.
По факту же у предприятия всегда есть полное и краткое наименование. Так вот в полном обычно все аббревиатуры раскрывают, а в кратком их используют, поскольку никаких ограничение на него в нет даже в принципе.

Comment: Конечно, словари бывают разные, но, я думаю, словари, подготовленные к изданию Институтом Русского языка, Академией наук вполне можно считать официальными. К сожалению, упомянутых мной  словарей у меня нет. информацию о нихя взяла с "Грамоты" и не знаю, кем они подготовлены. Но информации с этого сайта доверяю.

Comment: Следовательно, можно сделать вывод, что известное мне правило  остается незыблемым: при первом упоминании название организации должно приводиться полностью, так как любой человек, работающий с документом, не должен обращаться к дополнительным источникам, например, словарям, чтобы узнать, что скрывается за сокращением. Или есть другое мнение или правила, которые мне неизвестны.

Answer (score 0):

> В названиях органищзаций можно использовать любые сочетания букв и цифр

В самом названии - да. Хоть ООО "Чупакабра". Можно зарегистрировать фирму с абсолютно произвольным названием. Другой вопрос, что сокращения АО, АОЗТ (*устар.*), АООТ (*устар.*), ООО и пр. - это все правовые формы организации. Заодно туда же можно записать ИП (старый вариант - ПБОЮЛ). И, соответственно, наверняка существует их перечень. И вы выбираете из уже определенного законом набора, а не придумываете свой. Касательно ГУП (Государственное Унитарное Предприятие), ГУЗ (Государственное Учреждение Здравоохранения), ФГУП (Федеральный ГУП) и пр., думаю, соображения те же. Это все придумки наших государственных мужей и используются однообразно и весьма широко. Из новинок -  появилось ГКУ (Государственное Казенное Учреждение).